# breakpointer not available in scripts directory in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a ruby on rails newbie. In my app i created using scaffold, breakpointer is not there under scripts directory. When i copied breakpointer from somewhere and put under scripts directory, it was giving an error. Any pointers on this will be great..

Thanks,
Ayyappa

Comment: Could you tell us which version of Rails you used and what the error with the breakpointer was? Also does this happen again when you create a new Rails project?

Answer (score 1):

Breakpointer is no longer supported, mostly because it's incompatible with newer versions of Ruby. ruby-debug, aka rdebug, is the new standard. Try this

```
./script/server --debug
```

then put the keyword

```
debugger
```

where you'd like to have a debugging session. [Here is a good introduction screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/54-debugging-with-ruby-debug) on using rdebug.